# Is backed property safer than (lazy) in Swift?

Tags: swift, lazy-initialization

Is it safer to use computed property backed by another property, than to use `lazy` modifier in Swift?

```
// method 1: using LAZY variable
lazy var myVar:Int {
    // assume that this calculation takes
    // a lot of time and resources
    return 5
}
```

Now consider the following quote from Apple's Swift 2 (Pre-release):

> NOTE
>
> If a property marked with the `lazy` modifier is accessed by multiple
>   threads simultaneously and the property has not yet been initialized,
>   there is no guarantee that the property will be initialized only once.

Personally, I have been doing my own "lazy" logic like this:

Consider the alternative approach:

```
// method 2: using calculated property backed by another property
var myVar:Int? {
    if self._myVar != nil {
        return self._myVar
    }
    let aVar:Int = 5   // assume this is done after exhaustive calcuation
    self._myVar = aVar
    return self._myVar
}

var _myVar:Int? = nil
```

Using (method 2), do I get guarantee that the "exhaustive calculation" will only be executed once?

Comment: Method 2 does not guarantee anything that `lazy` does not.

Comment: @nhgrif Does this mean that both methods do the same exact thing? (except `lazy` method is shorter version?)

Comment: `lazy` is not only shorter, but probably more efficient in terms of both speed and memory usage.  I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proposed method 2 does not guarantee anything that `lazy` does not.

> ```
> // method 2: using calculated property backed by another property
> var myVar:Int? {
>     if self._myVar != nil {
>         return self._myVar
>     }
>     let aVar:Int = 5   // assume this is done after exhaustive calcuation
>     self._myVar = aVar
>     return self._myVar
> }
>
> var _myVar:Int? = nil
> ```

Moreover, it has the added pitfall of being an optional rather than a non-optional.  This would be slightly better as an implicitly unwrapped optional so we don't have to continuously unwrap it.

And, we can't set `myVar`.  Plus `_myVar` should be private.

But the problem is that you're not locking the initialization code down to be synchronized.

Suppose you have thread A start to access `myVar`.  The `if self._myVar != nil` check returns false, so we're not returning `self._myVar`.  Now we enter the exhaustive calculation.

Now before exhaustive calculation completes, Thread B tries accessing `myVar`.  Because Thread A has not completed exhaustive calculation yet, the `if self._myVar != nil` still returns false, and now Thread B does the exhaustive calculation.

Essentially, this is this the same problem that the `lazy` keyword gives you.... but you wrote a whole lot of code to do it that way when `lazy` would have sufficed.